# Odd jQuery hover behavior

Tags: jquery

I've spent awhile now reading the various other postings of jQuery hover issues, and trying different things to get my jQuery hover functions to work properly to no avail.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I want to hide/show a div within an li element with jQuery's hover event.

**What's happening**

The div hides/shows properly, but if the mouse is moved very quickly from one li element to the next, sometimes the hide (mouseleave) seems to not be getting executed. This leaves the div that is supposed to be hidden visible.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/vJPNT/11/

In the demo, you will see this effect. A div containing the link "Delete" appears as the mouse rolls over the li element, but if the mouse quickly jumps to the next li element, it does not always disappear.

Please let me know if any extra information is needed. Thanks.

Comment: +1 excellent problem elaboration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added console.log($(e.target)) to your two functions. It seems like some times e.target is one of the divs inside the li elements. This is probably because you catch a propagated hover event.

By changing $(e.target) to $(this) you should be fine.

```
function updateIn(e) {
    $(this).find('.actions').show();                
    console.log($(e.target));
}

function updateOut(e) {
    $(this).find('.actions').hide();  
    console.log($(e.target));
}

$('li.update').hover(updateIn, updateOut);
$('li.update .actions').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function updateIn(e) {
    $(this).find('.actions').show();  
    $(this).siblings().find('.actions').hide();  
}

function updateOut(e) {
    $(this).find('.actions').hide();  
}

$('li.update').hover(updateIn, updateOut);
$('li.update .actions').hide();
```

​Before every new `updateIn` you should hide the other shown actions.

Comment: Besides the fact that using e.target is not wise (as mentioned by Jørgen), your suggestion - although it's a safe bet - is not very efficient.

Comment: @TJ.I must've been writing this response as Jørgen answered, because I missed his reply. I realize this isn't the most efficient way but I maintain that as long as there aren't that many siblings, this is a very safe bet and that may outweigh the slight overhead on the user's system.

Answer (score 0):

Events occurs in differents elements. Your find function not return only `.update` class objects.  .update